# jsf table edit : retaining original values in bean in case reset button is pressed for row

Tags: data-binding, jsf

I have a data bean collection bind with my tomhawk table.
Now lets say i want to edit a row, so i make all the fields in that row editable and change values inside them, but on second thought i press "cancel edit" button.

To make all the fields editable, i have a flag in the bean bind with field's "readonly" property. So when i press "reset" button,  i set that flag to false.

Now problem is if i change values in field and then press "reset" button, values are updated in binding bean and original values are gone. Also i can query database only i case of modification.

SO how to retain original values in the bean here.

I am using JSF 1.2 and tomahawk components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `immediate="true"` to the command button. This way all input elements which are not set with `immediate="true"` will be skipped.

#### See also

- [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) - Explains among others the use of `immediate` attribute.